# Speech Recognition issue in Android 12

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I've an app which uses speech recognition. Target SDK is `31`. It was working fine but after updating device to `Android 12` it is not giving any result.

```java
    speechRecognizerIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_CALLING_PACKAGE, getPackageName());
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, 4000);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 4000);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 4000);
    speechRecognizerIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 5);
```

Getting null results in `OnResult()`

```java
    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
    ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
    }
```

I've already taken below `permission`

```java
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this change recently as well. onResults always returns null now but moving your code to the onPartailResults should return the speech result.

```
 @Override
 public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {
 ArrayList<String> matches = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was totally broken by Google speech engine updates.

The workaround fix is here:
[Why has SpeechRecognizer suddenly stopped working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71967536/why-has-speechrecognizer-suddenly-stopped-working/72141835)